# Will my ad still generate revenue that has been already loaded for hours

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I am using Facebook Audience Network and according to this [article](https://www.facebook.com/audiencenetwork/news-and-insights/required-changes-for-audience-network-publishers)

[image]

I am not caching ads but ads stays on screen without refreshing. I am loading all ads at once and they stay on screen until user closes the app.

```
private void initializeAds() {
        //ENABLE TESTING MODE
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            AdSettings.addTestDevice("alksdfj");//For testing ads
        }

        //NATIVE AD
        nativeAd = new NativeAd(this, "alksdjf");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Render the Native Ad Template
                View adView = NativeAdView.render(MainActivity.this, nativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_120);
                LinearLayout nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.native_ad_container);
                // Add the Native Ad View to your ad container
                nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

            }
        });

        //BANNER AD
        // Instantiate an AdView view
        adView = new AdView(this, "alksdjf", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

        // Find the Ad Container
        LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

        // Add the ad view to your activity layout
        adContainer.addView(adView);


        //Interstitial AD
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "alskdfj");
        // Set listeners for the Interstitial Ad
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial displayed callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                // Interstitial dismissed callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                // Ad error callback
                /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + adError.getErrorMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                Log.d("FACEBOOK_ADS", adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Show the ad when it's done loading.

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
            }
        });


        // Request an ad
        nativeAd.loadAd();
        adView.loadAd();

        // For auto play video ads, it's recommended to load the ad
        // at least 30 seconds before it is shown
        interstitialAd.loadAd();
        //interstitialAd.show();
    }
```

These ads can stay for long hours there. Also i am using interstitial ad that's loaded but only show to user when user unlock their device. (User can take hours to unlock their device)

I want in this scenario will theses ads generate revenue or do i need to re-request ads after some time like with cached ads.

Also BannerAds has refresh interval settings. Will that automatically refresh ads or do i need to refresh them as well

Comment: You should re-request the add. You might not be reusing the add, but from facebook side they don't know how you are using the add. They only know when you requested the add and when it has been clicked on.